# rich:calendar and popup width/size

Tags: calendar, richfaces

With WebKit-based browser when I go with the mouse over the popup-header (where the month is defined) the entire popup "collapses/shrinks".

I went then to the richfaces showcase page to see if the problem exists there too, but there the popup width/size doesn't changes.

I look at the code and tried to set the width in mine too with `style="width:200px"`, but there is no effect...

If I look with FireBug(F12) the element property `width` doesn't even appear:

```
element.style {
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
left: 459px;
top: 225px;
}
```

And here is the calendar code:

```
<td style="font-size: 5pt; border: 0; min-width: 60px">
    <rich:calendar id="startDate" value="#{detailModel.afterObject.startDate}"
        datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd" enableManualInput="true"
        style="width:200px"
        disabled="#{detailModel.mode == detailModel.viewMode}">
        <f:validateBean/>
    </rich:calendar>
    <h:messages for="startDate" style="color:red; font-size:12px;"/><br/>
</td>
```

Any suggestion why it doesn't work in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `style` applies to the invisible div that contains the input and the button, what you want to use is `popupStyle` or `popupClass`. See the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.3.X/4.3.4.Final/vdldoc/rich/calendar.html).